# Complete Classic asp page not rendering sometimes for some users (response.buffer?)

Tags: asp-classic, buffer, response

I've got a fairly complex classic asp page that for some users doesn't render completely at some times. I wonder if the response.buffer property might have something to do with that. Would setting it to **false** make it more likely to render completely? I suspect it's crapping out at some point but can't reproduce it on my end.

Comment: Try looking at the actual data flowing between the client and the server. Fiddler is great tool for seeing what is actually going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it had something to do with running too many database connections on the page on an already congested server, near as I can figure.

Answer (score 0):

If the client is receiving a partial page and buffering is enabled, a likely cause is the buffer limit being exceeded on the server side. In that case, disabling buffering would fix the problem. It all depends how you want the response sent - disabling buffering will send the content as and when it's written rather than waiting for the script to complete. An alternative would be to put in periodic calls to Response.Flush at sensible intervals to clear the buffer and send the content in chunks as you desire. It's difficult to be certain about a fix if you can't recreate the error; give it a try and let us know how it pans out :-).

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce it. I've also thought maybe the browser was caching parts of the page; it's difficult since I have a lot of JQuery and self-postbacks in the page. What can I do to trace what's happening if I remote to her computer?

Comment: Install Fiddler and monitor HTTP traffic with it.